# How to take Screenshot (Print Screen) from an embedded word document (quietly) in Excel document using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, screenshot, printscreen

I need take quietly Print Screen from an embedded Word document that is in my Excel doc and showing this image in a Splash Screen `User form`. How can I do that?

This because performing a read only Print Preview to user, before printing results that are collected in an embedded word document (with special format) by linked fields and thus by user acceptance running `PrintOut`.

Comment: I would say this is almost impossible to know at which position on the screen the print preview is that you need to screenshot. Why don't you just use the built-in print preview of that word file to show it in an extra window (and maybe hide ribbons etc). That would be easier. What I actually meant to say is re-think your approach from scratch I think you are on the wrong track.

Comment: Of course I only need showing Print Preview from embedded word document in MS-Excell workbook, for user acceptance. How can I perform print preview from an embedded word document in excel?

Comment: "That would be easier."; How can i show (quietly) print preview to user, from word document, that is embedded in excel one with VBA?